# Extjs 5.1: method in a ViewController not invoked

Tags: javascript, viewcontroller, extjs5, listeners

I'm using Extjs 5.1, I would like to invoke a method in a ViewController
Here is my View:

```
Ext.define("bdociTabletProto.view.main.Main", {
extend: "Ext.container.Container",
requires: ['bdociTabletProto.view.main.MainController'],
controller: "mainController",

initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;
    me.layout = "border";
    ....
    me.items = [...];
    me.listeners = {
        afterlayout: 'onMainAfterLayout',
        scope: 'controller'
    };
    me.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

and here is the ViewController where I implement the `onMainAfterLayout` method:

```
Ext.define("bdociTabletProto.view.main.MainController", {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
alias: 'controller.mainController',

onMainAfterLayout: function (container) {
    var me = this;
    var docNavigator = me.getView().docNavigator;
    var workflowActions = me.getView().workflowActions;
    docNavigator.setHeight(container.getHeight());
    docNavigator.setWidth(container.getWidth() / 4);
    workflowActions.setPosition((container.getWidth() - workflowActions.getWidth()) / 2, 0);
}
});
```

this throws an Exception: **[E] Ext.util.Event.getFireInfo(): Unable to dynamically resolve scope for "afterlayout" listener on ext-comp-1010**

At the first time I wrote the listener without scope, but after googling the problem, I found that in the new Version of Extjs (5.1) I should set the Scope property.

Without setting the scope property, the error is like that :  **Uncaught Error: No method named "onMainAfterLayout" on bdociTabletProto.view.main.Main**

Any one can help me please??
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution:

- Add this in the ViewController

  `control: {
      '#': {
          afterlayout: 'onMainAfterLayout'
      }
  },`
- remove the listeners from the view

Comment: Refenrece for this solution can be found in the Listeners and Event Domains section of http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/application_architecture/view_controllers.html